# How to use multiple pandas functions in a single variable python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to drop a column level and columns to the right, from data downloaded from yahoo finance.

```
FAANG = yf.download(['AAPL','GOOGL','NFLX','META','AMZN','SPY'],
                    start = '2008-01-01',end = '2022-12-31')
FAANG_AC = FAANG.drop(FAANG.columns[6:36],axis=1)

FAC = FAANG_AC.droplevel(0,axis=1)
```

How do I combine `.drop` and `.droplevel` into a single variable, so that I do not have to use multiple variables in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use intermediate variables. You can chain everything:

```
FAANG = (yf.download(['AAPL','GOOGL','NFLX','META','AMZN','SPY'],
                    start='2008-01-01', end = '2022-12-31')
           .drop(FAANG.columns[6:36], axis=1)
           .droplevel(0, axis=1)
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `inplace=True` as a parameter for when calling those methods. Like:

```
FAANG.drop(FAANG.columns[6:36],axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Careful: it will modify the `FAANG` variable.

Reference: https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/pandas/inplace-true-parameter